# Adding instances to a list

Tags: python, instances

**Overview**

My group has built hardware that needs to communicate with software that we're supposed to write. However we all are at a standstill because we can't figure this issue out. We have searched a lot but to no avail. We would love ANY help.

This is the GUI we're supposed to use and as help to our final part we have to code an Add feature so you can choose several variables instead of all or one, which is the case now. As you see the Add button is there, but it has no functionality currently.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/VWLFX.png

**What we need to code**

We need the Add button, to add whatever is chosen in the dropdown menu and shown in the textbox for any amount of items.

We tried to do

```
list_name.append(varible_name)
```

But it returns the error

```
TypeError: descriptor 'append' requires a 'list' but got a 'instance'
```

We did try with other code after googling but at this point I nor my partners can remeber any of them.

I will not post our code, since some of the info is sensitive(the rest of the gui which is cropped out) - but i don't need to. Any arbitrary names of each component is fine - we will work on it from there to implement it to our code.
Everything works except the Add, so there are no other errors in the code.

I hope the info is sufficient enough to understand the issue fully.

Comment: Without the code, there's no possible way we can help you. Please read [help], [faq], and [mcve].

Comment: You should be able to create a toy example from your code that you can post here.

Comment: is `list_name` a real list or a class with `append` method ?

Comment: When you created your list did you write `list_name = list` rather than `list_name = list()` or `list_name = []` ?

Comment: Is list_name an element in a list rather than a list of names itself?

Comment: I see in the code that its in the format of list_name = list |

list_name is a list and not a class furas |


Thanks for the links Morgan

Answer (score 1):

You have assigned the `list` class to `list_name`.

```
class Foo: pass

f = Foo()
list_name = list   # whoops!  should be list() 
list_name.append(f)
```

Gives

```
TypeError: descriptor 'append' requires a 'list' object but received a 'instance'
```